# Using @font-face for Segoe UI font

Tags: fonts

I have Google for an hour now and I can't find out if I can use @font-face using the Segoe UI font. Would any body know if the license for the font will allow me to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about license conditions.

Comment: 2016: Microsoft now offers an open source version called Selawik: https://github.com/winjs/winstrap/tree/master/dist/fonts

Answer (score 28):

As the other answers note, **Segoe UI is not available for use in web apps not made by Microsoft or their agents**. To answer the title of your question, however, I'd like to point out that Microsoft themselves use Segoe UI in their web apps via @font-face, eg, from the [Microsoft Surface 2 CSS](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/assets/css/fonts/all/fonts.css):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/normal/segoeui.eot');
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/normal/segoeui.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/normal/segoeui.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/normal/segoeui.svg#SegoeUI') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Semibold';
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/semibold/seguisb.eot');
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/semibold/seguisb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/semibold/seguisb.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/semibold/seguisb.svg#SegoeUISemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Bold';
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/bold/segoeuib.eot');
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/bold/segoeuib.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), /* Wrong format will tell IE9+ to ignore and use WOFF instead. MSHAR-2822 */
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/bold/segoeuib.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/bold/segoeuib.svg#SegoeUIBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/light/segoeuil.eot');
    src: url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/light/segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/light/segoeuil.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/surface/Assets/css/fonts/all/light/segoeuil.svg#SegoeUILight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Even projects like [Metro UI - that look exactly like Windows 8](http://metroui.org.ua/css/modern.css) - use OpenSans:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Open Sans Bold"), local("OpenSans-Bold"), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzJ1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local("Open Sans Light"), local("OpenSans-Light"), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTZ1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: local("Open Sans Extrabold"), local("OpenSans-Extrabold"), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/EInbV5DfGHOiMmvb1Xr-hp1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

I would recommend OpenSans.

Comment: Thank you, Nailer.  Open Sans looks more than acceptable to me.

Answer (score 11):

You can't license Segoe UI from Microsoft without direct contact, you can license the mono font from Ascender Corp who are linked to from Microsoft webpage for Segoe UI, however it is not the same as Segoe UI.

I would suggest Open Sans as an alternative to the Segoe UI font, it is quite similar and has much more open licensing for using as webfont (that link is actually to Google's hosted version of the font) - So you could have Segoe as the main font then fall back to Open Sans on non Windows 7+ Systems.

Answer (score 3):

You can technically create a web font using any font in your "C:\Windows\Fonts\" folder.
In most circumstances (including Segoe UI), **you aren't allowed to do this** due to licensing restrictions. Instead, I would recommend [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) as a good alternative to Segoe UI.

However, if you are allowed to do this, you can follow these steps:

1. Retrieve your font from your "C:\Windows\Fonts\" folder. (Windows)
2. Convert the font into any other formats that you desire for compatibility (TTF, EOT, SVG, WOFF)
3. Create a CSS file with the following code in it:

   ```
   @font-face{
       font-family: 'FontName';
       src: url('path/to/webfont.eot');
       src: url('path/to/webfont.woff'),
            url('path/to/webfont.ttf'),
            url('path/to/webfont.svg')
   }
   ```
4. Now in your main CSS file, use the "font-family" tag to select your web font.

I will state again the importance of having a valid license for the web font, when purchasing a license **make sure that you have the rights to use the font on the web**. Some fonts may come with a web font package with the CSS and fonts already prepared for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same font on that page. The font on that page is Segoe UI Mono. As far as I know, Segoe UI is supposed to appear only on Microsoft Windows.